# How to measure the reliability of a consensus ranking (problem from Kemeny-Snell book)

Tags: reliability, ranking, order-statistics

Suppose that $k$ experts are each asked to rank a set of $n$ objects in order or preference. Let allow ties in the rankings.

John Kemeny and Laurie Snell in their 1962 year book ["Mathematical models in the Social Sciences"](http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015002661802;view=1up;seq=34) propose to solve next problem:

> PROJECT $1$.
>   **Develop a measure of the reliability of a consensus ranking
>   by $k$ experts.** For example, this may be based on the largest possible change that can be brought about by changing the ranking of a single expert. (Attention must be paid to the possibility of multiple consensus rankings.) Prove some theorems concerning the most and least reliable consensuses possible for a given $k$.

The book gives notation for rankings and method for rankings aggregation (i.e. getting one "collective" ranking from many "individuals"). But no answer given for the problem above.

First, I thought about [Kendall's $W$ coefficient of concordance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall%27s_W), but it looks like it doesn't suit. Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

As a measure of reliability of a consensus ranking by $k$ experts you can use the $\tau$-extended by Emond and Mason. 
For extensive explanations take a look to:
http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/mcda.313/full
or 
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377221715008048